# Information on Oracle MKSTORE utility for creating wallet

Tags: oracle, wallet

I'm looking for more information about the utility MKSTORE that can be used for creating and modifying a Wallet. I would like to know things like what the -createALO option is and what the difference is between -createSSO and CreateLSSO. A link to the information would be fine or a document number on MOS. My goal is to script the Wallet creation and am wondering if these options can help me in any way.

Comment: So is the LSSO the same as the SAML lightweight browser single sign on? The ALO sounds so familiar but I can't place it. If these are what I think they are then they're experimental, hence undocumented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General Information about Oracle Wallet is in the [Advanced Security Guide](http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/nonsun/oracle/11.2.0.1.0/E11882_01_200909/network.112/e10746/toc.htm).

[This is the link](http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/nonsun/oracle/11.2.0.1.0/E11882_01_200909/network.112/e10746/asoappf.htm) to managing wallets from the command line using the general orapki tool.

[This is the link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm) to managing wallets using the MKSTORE command specific to credentials storage.

*add

[Here is some q&a on the steps on asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:142212348066#2145719700346806118). He also notes an Oracle bug 4395883 that can affect using connect identifiers 4, 8 or 12 bytes in length.

[Here is a blog entry](http://oracleinout.blogspot.com/2010/01/playing-with-mkstore.html) that contains a script for rapidly creating wallet entries. [Another entry on that blog](http://oracleinout.blogspot.com/2010/04/mkstore-ora-01017-invalid.html) about the bug above.

[Another blog entry](http://davidalejomarcos.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/securing-passwords-on-scripts-using-oracle-wallet/) about the whole process.

-createSSO means autologin (aka no password required)

-createLSSO means -auto_login_local (require the hostname matches where the wallet was created)

-createALO means -auto_login_only (require the hostname and the user the wallet was created on/under to match)

This does not appear to be documented under mkstore but is documented under orapki which is a companion utility.  Note auto_login_local security feature can be spoofed and offers little additional protection.  Search the web and you can find more details about why auto_login_local is ineffective.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoappf.htm#ASOAG9833

Comment: I really don't think this is what Leigh as asking about, but it may be all there is.

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like that bug is usually what gets people if they try on a default 10.2 (10.2.0.1) install. The patch is in the 10.2.x upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

My goal with this question was to determine how mkstore could be scripted.  Here is the method I came up with using Powershell.  Here are the requirements:

1. PowerShell is installed.
2. Scripting is enabled (`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` run as administrator).
3. The script is in c:\oracle\WalletCreator.
4. Wasp.dll from [Windows Automation Snapin for PowerShell](http://wasp.codeplex.com/releases/view/22118) is located in the script folder.

The wallet will be created in c:\oracle\Wallets.  Here is the script.

```
Import-Module c:\oracle\WalletCreator\WASP.dll

$WalletCreated = 0

cls
Write-Host "                                                           " -foregroundcolor White -backgroundcolor DarkRed
Write-Host "   Warning: This script will delete your current wallet.   " -foregroundcolor White -backgroundcolor DarkRed
Write-Host "                                                           " -foregroundcolor White -backgroundcolor DarkRed

do {
    #Get credentials
    Write-Host " " 
    Write-Host " New Wallet Entry                                          " -foregroundcolor White -backgroundcolor DarkGreen
    Write-Host "    To exit press return without entering anything.        " -foregroundcolor White -backgroundcolor DarkGreen
    $DB = Read-Host "Connection Name"
    if ($DB -eq "") {
       Return
    }
    $Username = Read-Host "       Username"
    if ($Username -eq "") {
       Return
    }
    $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "       Password" 

    #Convert from SecureString to String.
    $BasicString = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
    $Password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BasicString)
    if ($Password -eq "") {
       Return
    }

    if ($WalletCreated -eq 0) {
        #Create folder in case it doesn't exist.
        md c:\oracle\Wallets -Force | Out-Null

        #Delete any wallet in the folder now.
        del c:\oracle\Wallets\*.* | Out-Null

        #Get GUID for wallet password.
        $WalletPassword = [guid]::NewGuid().toString()
        $WalletPassword = $WalletPassword + "`r"

        #Create Wallet.
        Start-Process -FilePath mkstore -ArgumentList "-wrl c:\oracle\Wallets\ -create"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        Select-Window -ProcessName cmd | Select -First 1 | Send-Keys -keys $WalletPassword
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
        Select-Window -ProcessName cmd | Select -First 1 | Send-Keys -keys $WalletPassword

        $WalletCreated = 1
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    }

    #Create Credential.
    $CC = "-wrl c:\oracle\Wallets\ -createCredential " + $DB + " " 
    $CC = $CC + $Username + " " + $Password
    Start-Process -FilePath mkstore -ArgumentList $CC
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
    Select-Window -ProcessName cmd | Select -First 1 | Send-Keys -keys $WalletPassword
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
} 
until ($DB -eq "")
```